# Java performing code only from constructor's subclass

Tags: java

Is it possible to protect from performing code placed in superclass constructor? In this example the output is

`From Person
From Student`

but I don't need to print out `From Person`. If I delete `super(a, n);` then program will not compile. Is it possible to print out only message from subclass?

```
class Person {

private int age;
private String name;

public Person(int a, String n) {
    this.age = a;
    this.name = n;
    System.out.println("From Person");
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int a) {
    this.age = a;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String n) {
    this.name = n;
}
}

class Student extends Person {

private String specialization;

public Student(int a, String n, String s) {
    super(a, n);
    specialization = s;
    System.out.println("From Student");
}

public String getSpecialization() {
    return specialization;
}

public void setSpecialization(String s) {
    this.specialization = s;
}
}

public class Classes {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Student student_Jack = new Student(20, "Jack", "IT");
}
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Delete the line `System.out.println("From Person");` ...?

Comment: Do you want to achieve that the complete constructor logic of the superclass is not invoked or do you only want he printout to disappear?

Comment: You could create an empty constructor in Person and then just call super();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `super(a,n)` you should use your methods for setting those variables that you have made.

```
public Student(int a, String n, String s) {
    setAge(a);
    setName(n);
    specialization = s;
    System.out.println("From Student");
}
```

You must also add an empty constructor in person.

```
public Person(){}
```

This will give you the same functionality, without needing to call the super constructor.

Comment: Then is an error: `Implicit super constructor Person() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor`

Comment: Updated answer.